# How to change the default action of buttons in bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I would like to override the action of the current time button in the `bootstrap-datetimepicker`. I am making a tool which takes the current time of a particular city, the name of the city whose time user wants. This works vice versa.

So when user clicks on the current time button of the the city whose time he wants he should get the current time in the city instead of the system time (which is the default action of `bootstrap-datetimepicker`).

Check the documentation of datetimepicker here:
 [eonasdan - bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Check the tool here: [Uditchugh link](http://uditchugh.me/pt)

Check the code of tool here: [Github timeconverter](https://github.com/udit96rc/TimeConverter)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want using the locale() function of the bs datetimepicker lib.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#locale

For this you need to have a list of locales associated to your cities.

Comment: No. Its totally different than what I need. Please read the description once again.